# RegEx to remove unwanted character in a patterns in python

Tags: python, regex

I have imported a text file in a variable using the following:

```py
with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
    logdata = file.read()
```

In this text file, the following string structure has been repeated.

197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0"

Using RegEx I wrote, the following pattern:

```
pattern = """
(?P<host>\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)
(\s-\s)
(?P<user_name>\w*\d*|-)
(\s\[) 
(?P<time>\d*/\w*/\d*:\d*:\d*:\d*\s-\d*)
(]\s)
(?P<request>".*")

"""

cleanWebLog = list()
for i in re.finditer(pattern, logdata, re.VERBOSE):
    cleanWebLog.append(i.groupdict())
```

**Code Output:**

[{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': '"DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0"'}]

The problem is that in the request, I want whatever that is in the quotation but without the quotation in the output.

Comment: You could put the double quotes outside of the capture group `"(?P<request>.*)"`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you get the *'output'* by `print(cleanWebLog)`. What you see as output is a **representation** of the list containing a dictionary.

In other words what you see in the *'output'* is not what the RegEx delivered as it delivered the values **without** the quotation marks.

Try: `print( cleanWebLog[0]['host'] )` to see that the dictionary key and the value store a string without the quotation marks.

I further guess that your goal is to get a string representation of the generated list but without the quotation marks. You can achieve that by printing using appropriate formatting of the print() output. This can be done for example using following code:

```
cleanWebLog = [{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', g'request': '"DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0"'}]
print(cleanWebLog)

print('[{', end='') 
for key, value in cleanWebLog[0].items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}, ', end='')
print('}]')
```

giving:

```
[{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': '"DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0"'}]
[{host: 197.109.77.178, user_name: kertzmann3129, time: 21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700, request: "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0", }]
```

In other words there is no need to change anything about the RegEx.

Hope this answers your question.

**Update considering the comment**:

As suggested already by *The fourth bird* the following

```
pattern = """
(?P<host>\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)
(\s-\s)
(?P<user_name>\w*\d*|-)
(\s\[) 
(?P<time>\d*/\w*/\d*:\d*:\d*:\d*\s-\d*)
(]\s)
"(?P<request>.*)"
"""
```

will satisfy your request in the comment.

Comment: The problem is with the 'request' key. I want the value for that key to be without the quotation.

Comment: See my updated answer for the solution of your problem.